# Как получить время из PostgreSQL в том же самом часовом поясе, в котором и было изначально загружено в БД, вместо UTC?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timezone

- Есть данные, которые через Django загружаются в базу в формате “2015-10-31 17:00:00+03” (aware форма времени).
- PostgreSQL имеет свойство сохранять время в UTC.
- В pgAdmin-е я вижу время не в UTC, а в том виде, в котором было изначально загружено значение, т.е. “2015-10-31 17:00:00+03”.

К примеру я загружаю новые данные, но перед заливкой в БД нужно сравнить эти данные со значениями, которые уже есть в БД.
Новая порция идет в формате:

"2015-10-31 17:00:00+03“,
а значения из БД вытягиваются уже в UTC, т.е.

”2015-10-31 14:00:00+00".

Как сделать так, чтоб значение вытягивалось из БД не в UTC, а в том же часовом поясе, в котором и было залито?

```
test = Shows.objects.get(name='Test')
test.date_time # выдает в UTC, а нужно чтоб было +3
```

П.С Хардкодить нельзя. Нужно получать именно тот часовой пояс из БД, что и был залит изначально со значением, так как заливаться значения могут с разным часовым поясом.

Comment: Ваше поле `date_time` имеет тип `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?

Comment: Да, мое поле имеет именно этот тип

Comment: Что вам мешает просто конвертировать время в локальное?

Comment: @Bezarius, я нахожусь в Москве, хочу посмотреть расписания в кинотеатрах Киева (еду к примеру в командировку). Зачем мне конвертировать в московский часовой пояс, если я пойду на сеанс в Киеве и мне нужно киевское время? Конвертировать можно время, которое не привязано к географии (посты на форумах), а у меня идет привязка к месту, по этому часть данных в БД заливается для Украины, часть для России, и тд по СНГ, и все эти данные имеют datetime со своим часовым поясом, который так же заливается (как я понимаю) в БД. Я хочу на сайт выводить эти данные в том часовом поясе, в котором они находятся

Comment: @TitanFighter примените toLocalTime на стороне клиента, и тогда будучи в Киеве вы получите Киевское время.

Comment: @Bezarius это я понимаю) Мне же нужно будучи в Москве увидеть киевское расписание по киевскому времени. Если же я поеду во Владивосток, то я хочу увидеть опять же расписание во часовому поясу Владивостока. Зачем мне расписание Владивостока в московском часовом поясе?

Comment: @TitanFighter в ответе я вам указал как работать с различными таймзонами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Документация django говорит](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql), что PostgreSQL преобразует местное время (время c часовой зоной, указанной для текущего соединения с базой данной) в UTC при сохранении и наоборот преобразует из UTC в местное время при чтении.

> Как сделать так, чтоб значение вытягивалось из БД не в UTC, а в том же часовом поясе, в котором и было залито?

Если `USE_TZ=True`, то для соединения используется UTC временна́я зона, то есть postgresql видит только UTC.

Если Вы сохраняете время, принадлежащее нескольким временны́м зонам, то дополнительно к самому времени с типом `timestamptz`, сохраняйте также и имя временно́й зоны (например, `'Europe/Kiev'` или `'Europe/Moscow'`).

Если важно получить тоже самое локальное время, даже если правила изменились (если другая версия tzdata используется), то сохраняйте также явно текущий utc offset в минутах и другую необходимую информацию отдельно.

Зная, UTC время и имя зоны, можно получить желаемое время (используя текущие правила (tzdata version)) в Питон коде:

```
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

local = utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Kiev'))
```

Чтобы [запросить время из базы данных напрямую в заданной временно́й зоне](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5065131/4279):

```
select your_date at time zone 'Europe/Kiev' from your_table
```

Зная, UTC время и utc offset в минутах:

```
local = utc.astimezone(pytz.FixedOffset(120))
```

Чтобы получить время в текущей временно́й зоне для django (зона, которая используется для показа в шаблонах):

```
from django.utils import timezone

local = timezone.localtime(utc)
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Я читал доку джанго, и догу Пострегса, но оставлял надежду, что я не всю инфу нашел и все таки как то такое провернуть можно. Я предполагал, что если в БД пишется время с типом TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, то с этой записи можно вытянуть часовой пояс обратно. Придется отдельно сохранять еще и названия часового пояса.

Comment: Хороший ответ, правда похоже mysql и sqllite немного по другому. Насколько я понимаю они никогда не меняют время а всегда сохраняют то что записано перед вызовом .save()? В документации этого не нашел но тут http://bovs.org/post/166/Casovye-poasa-v-Django-na-prostyh-primerah указано такое поведение

Comment: Текущий вопрос про PostgreSQL. Если вас интересует поведение других БД, то [задайте отдельный вопрос (можно на текущий сослаться для контекста)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> utc = pytz.utc
>>> utc.zone
'UTC'
>>> eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> eastern.zone
'US/Eastern'
>>> amsterdam = timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

>>> loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
>>> print loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
2002-10-27 06:00:00 EST-0500

>>> ams_dt = loc_dt.astimezone(amsterdam)
>>> ams_dt.strftime(fmt)
'2002-10-27 12:00:00 CET+0100'
```